# Are there ArcIMS instances still around or phased out?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcims

My understanding is there are few companies still using ArcIMS and I am wondering if it is still alive or phased out?

Comment: ArcIMS will no longer be supported with the release of ArcGIS 10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still alive, but that will [not be the case starting with 10.1](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcims/index.html). From the [Esri site](http://www.esri.com/products/products-alpha.html):

> Esri’s development of ArcIMS is now limited. Our server GIS
>   development efforts are devoted primarily to ArcGIS Server.

As far as existing services, I know the BLM has IMS services available through geocommunicator.gov, if you add that as a ArcIMS Server connection in ArcCatalog.

Comment: Thanks Chad ! What happens if they migrate to 10.1 and what happens to their ArcIMS ? Will it run ok if they decide to migrate to 10 and separate with it ?

Comment: @PROBERT - [ArcIMS will not ship with 10.1](http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/supportcenter/archive/2010/10/11/announcement-for-existing-arcims-users-update-to-the-deprecation-plan.aspx). Organizations will have to come up with migration plans of their own just as they had to do with the deprecation of VBA support and WebADF.

Answer (score 2):

I am, strangley nough, working on ArcIMS today and an awful lot of businesses, especially government organisations, are using ArcIMS in 9.3.1 guise, due to limitations invoked in 10.  It is not being developed further with 10.1, but most would argue it wasn't really developed since 9.3.1 SP3.

Goecortex, a Canadian company were using ArcIMS as part of their core software, but I believe this is now on ArcGIS Server.

I think the message is, drop IMS, move to AGS.

Comment: [Latitude Geographics](http://www.latitudegeo.com/) did indeed start out with ArcIMS customization, but they have moved to ArcGIS Server as their core product, and their stuff is pretty damn slick, by the way. Looks like they offer [ArcIMS to ArcGIS Server migration services](http://www.geocortex.com/arcgis-server-services/arcims-web-adf-migration/).

Comment: To be frank Chad, I love Geocortex Essentials, top stuff and I recommend it for all of my clients.  I had a presentation from them a couple of years back, with portfolio sites, and was very impressed with the Web 2 stuff.  I was using it on 9.3.1 and was impressed then.

Comment: The story I heard is Geocortex spent 60K manhours migrating from ArcIMS to Web ADF, only to have Esri announce that 10.0 would be that last release for that too. It seems like platform lifespans are rapidly shrinking. GeoCortex now uses Esri's REST.  After looking at [OData](http://www.odata.org/) that too is starting to show its age.

Comment: I think a few things also waylayed ESRI and GeoCortex too, one of them being WIndows deciding not to support Flash on Windows Mobile.  I know of one company alone who didn't purchase Geocortex as they really weren't sure about platform support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - ArcIMS is still in use. Here in Denmark we have a few web sites based on ArcIMS - the largest part of the GIS web sites is based on ArcGIS Server though.

An important information about ArcIMS 10, is that this release does not include the ArcMap Server, meaning that you can no longer create map services based on mxd-files - only axl is supported.
I wonder if, this is Esri's way of telling ArcIMS users to "convert" to ArcGIS Server?? It is not fun to realize that all your mxd-based map services now must be converted to axl if you want to use ArcIMS 10. Furthermore the axl format does not support all the things, that mxd does.

Comment: If you have to convert, you may as well convert to one of the many open source map servers.

Answer (score 0):

We have several State and County bodies here in WA using ArcIMS still. Off the top of my head I know Snohomish County GIS still is running IMS based services that can easily be found.